# VB.Net - Populating Arrays

Tags: arrays, vb.net, for-loop

So, I have this code below that populates an array.

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim n(10) As Integer
        Dim i, j As Integer

        For i = 0 to 10 step 3
            n(i) = i + 100
        Next i
        For j = 0 to 10
            Console.WriteLine("Element({0}) = {1}", j, n(j))
        Next j
        Console.ReadLine()
        End Sub
        End Module
```

I' am wondering why does the output of the code
is

```
Element({0}) = 100
Element({1}) = 0
Element({2}) = 0
Element({3}) = 103
Element({4}) = 0
Element({5}) = 0
Element({6}) = 106
Element({7}) = 0
Element({8}) = 0
Element({9}) = 109
```

What I intented to is this

```
Element({0}) = 100
Element({1}) = 103
Element({2}) = 106
Element({3}) = 109
Element({4}) = 112
Element({5}) = 115
Element({6}) = 118
Element({7}) = 121
Element({8}) = 124
Element({9}) = 127
```

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Step 3 will do that to you.

Comment: To clarify @LarsTech's comment, when you do `For i = 0 to 10 step 3`, you're essentially skipping every third number, so the only integers in the array that will be assigned will be those with the indexes 0, 3, 6 and 9.

Comment: @AlexM thankyou for your comment! 'For i = 0 to 10 Step 3' when I run this code 'Console.WriteLine(i)' has an output of 0369?? it didn't skip any number like the one on my example??

Comment: You have to go the other way around.  Get rid of the step.  It's just `n(i) = (i * 3) + 100`

Comment: I just deleted my answer because I saw after posting that @LarsTech had already answered the question in his comment. I had a bit of an explanation to go with it though

Comment: Thankyou @LarsTech

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Step 3`, move `3` to next line:

```vb
For i = 0 to 10
     n(i) = 3 * i + 100
Next i
```

If anything is unclear, feel free to ask me.

(Edit: I see this was answered in comments, I did not read them before.)